# AS3 hitTestObject not working at all

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6, hittest

I've been working on a large project in Flash CS6 and ActionScript 3 which includes jigsaws etc. I have been using hitTestObject throughout the project and it had been working fine, then all of a sudden it stopped working. It won't work in any new instances or even where it worked before. I created a small test piece, and this isn't working either:

```
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   hit_txt.visible = false;

   object2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);

   function drag(e:MouseEvent = null):void {
      object2_mc.startDrag();
   } 

   if (object2_mc.hitTestObject(object1_mc)) {
      hit_txt.visible = true;
   }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you got any runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not stating when to do the checking of the hit test. So either you check by enter frame, or while you move the object

```
object2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, move);
function move(e:MouseEvent = null):void
{
    if (object2_mc.hitTestObject(object1_mc))
    {
        hit_txt.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code doesn't work but you were absolutely right about needing to state when to do the test. Thanks again, you've really saved me!